# jQuery countdown not restarting

Tags: jquery, date, countdown, jquery-countdown

I'm using the jquery countdown to countdown to a specific date and time. When the counter expires I want the counter to be destroyed, restarted with the current time plus 10 minutes and with a new expiry-function.

But for some reason, when my first timer runs out the expiry function for the second timer is executed and the 10-min countdown starts.

I have tried several combinations including 'option', moving the function around...but I can't make it work so that the last function (a simple console log) is called as the final expiry function.

Here is my code:

```
var select = new Date(data.select);  //date from server

$('#counter').countdown({
    until: select,
    format: 'dhms',
    layout: ' ({h<}{hn} timer {h>}{m<}{mnn} minutter {m>}{s<}{snn} sekunder{s>})',
    onExpiry: onCounter
});

function onCounter() {
    $('#counter').countdown('destroy');
    $('#counter').countdown({
        until: '+10m',
        format: 'ms',
        layout: ' ({m<}{mnn} minutter {m>}{s<}{snn} sekunder{s>})',
        onExpiry: console.log('times up') // last function to be called
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onCounter` `onExpiry` is not a function, so is executed immediately rather than on expiry:

```
function onCounter() {
    $('#counter').countdown('destroy');
    $('#counter').countdown({
        until: '+10m',
        format: 'ms',
        layout: ' ({m<}{mnn} minutter {m>}{s<}{snn} sekunder{s>})',
        onExpiry: function() { console.log('times up'); } 
    });
}
```

---

or you can create a new function and call that, the same way you do with the first:

```
function onFinalCounter() {
    console.log("times up");
}

function onCounter() {
    $('#counter').countdown('destroy');
    $('#counter').countdown({
        until: '+10m',
        format: 'ms',
        layout: ' ({m<}{mnn} minutter {m>}{s<}{snn} sekunder{s>})',
        onExpiry: onFinalCounter
    });
}
```